# tagEditor , facing Cannot read property 'maxTags' of undefined ERROR

Tags: jquery-tageditor

I am working with tagEdotor jQuery , When try to populate date from different rows its throwing Cannot read property 'maxTags' of undefined error .

if i refresh the page and then click again it works fine.

I used $('#new_os_EmailAddress').tagEditor('destroy'); as well before initialising it ... but facing same issue.